# How to find out if a Wi-Fi is with or without an internet connection

Tags: ios, wifi, connectivity, nwpathmonitor

I'd like to find out if a Wi-Fi has internet connection or not. Sometimes our devices are connected with Wi-Fi, but the Wi-Fi doesn't have an internet connection.

NWPathMonitor or Connectivity thirdparty. I tried it, but it is not fool proof.

I know I can write a method to ping a server, but this is a very ineffective and costly affair.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @RaviMan, can you make a request to a known working web to see if it answer back to you?

Comment: @wazowski - I'll have to check this so often and there could be time delay in getting the result as well. So I'm looking for something instant and from framework or thirdparty

Comment: Well, even solution you will find will need to check internet via connection, so a ping to a known server will be enough, or a fast server like google, etc...

Comment: Not really looking to do by pinging

Comment: And did you try Reachability pod?

Comment: This line make it fast and clean: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

    return (URL != NULL ) ? YES : NO;
}

Comment: But what if the wifi is temporarily slow hence got timed out ? You see what am saying.. I would like to go with some kind of Apple API which can gurantee or some thirdparty which is widely popular and guarantee the accuracy which is fair enough

Answer (score 5):

The only way to know *for sure* if a network has an Internet connection is to try and make a connection to the Internet.  There is nothing on the device that you can query to get the answer.

Even if there were it would have to resort to polling/pinging since connectivity can change at any instant.

A WiFi connection can transition from no-Internet to Internet when the user completes a Hotspot login form.  A WiFi connection can transition from Internet to no-Internet if the upstream Internet connection fails in some way.  A WiFi connection may be connected to the Internet but not be able to communicate with the specific host your app needs due to a routing failure or some other issue.

For all of these reasons Apple actively discourages "pre flight" checks.  Even if a check passes a network operation can still fail due to a change in network status that occurred a microsecond later.  It is also unnecessary overhead as it is generally a safe assumption that most devices have some sort of Internet connection most of the time, particularly if the device is an iPhone.

You need to handle errors anyway. Just try the operation and see what happens.  If there is no network connection it will fail pretty quickly.

If you want to provide more feedback to the user then you could begin actively checking Internet connectivity with exponential back off in response to a connection error.

That way your app isn't constantly "pinging".

You can also use the error to start a process that uses  [`SCNetworkReachability`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/scnetworkreachability-g7d) to check connectivity for you.  Rather than using that framework directly, particularly if you are writing in Swift, you might like to use something that wraps it and makes it more accessible like Ashley Mills' [Reachability.swift](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift)

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "exponential back off in response to connection error ?"

Comment: Can I not make use of reachability class to check active internet connection in someways ?

Comment: Yes, you can use reachability, but all that it does is make periodic connections to a host you specify.  It is slightly better than ping in that it actually uses an http connection, but http connections are more expensive than ping.  You could use reachability in response to a network error; Probably 99% of the time most devices do have an active Internet connection.

Comment: Exponential back off means you check and if the check fails you wait, say, 1 second and check again. If it still fails then you wait 2 seconds and check again, if it still fails you wait 4 seconds and so on.  You can set a ceiling so that once you get to 64 seconds the time period stops doubling

Comment: If you don't mind , could you share some code snippet for this pinging exponential mechanism please , I'd really appreciate.

Comment: Creating an ICMP ping isn’t simple code. I think you would be better off using Reachabity.Swift, but the core of exponential backoff is something like `retryDelay = min(retryDay*2,60)`. This would double the retry period until you reach 60 seconds and then keep it at 60 seconds